# Shared variables in TypeScripts just like in JS

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

In JS I am able to connect scripts inside HTML. Assume I have two scripts `first.js` and `second.js`, so I can make this:

```
<script src=".../first.js"></script>
<script src=".../second.js"></script>
```

and then I am able to use any variable of `first.js` in `second.js`
How to reach such a result via TypeScript keeping those scripts as separated files?

Comment: I can't speak to whether or not this is technically feasible, but if you're relying on variables local to another arbitrary JavaScript file, it's likely your design needs some re-work. Generally speaking, these files should be self-contained (with exceptions for frameworks with proper module definitions, `export`s, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to avoid globals, you can extract the shared parts into a separate module:

shared.ts

```
const MY_VAR = 1337;

export { MY_VAR }
```

and use it in one of the other scripts:

first.ts:

```
import { MY_VAR } from './shared';

console.log(MY_VAR);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare this in your TypeScript file so that the compiler knows it exists.

`declare var x: string; // The variable name should be the same as in your JS files.`

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in a comment, you don't want to rely on implicitly declared shared variables. This can have some nasty side-effects and often is really hard to debug. However there are situations where there is no other way. You can use the `globalThis` object to share variables between different modules, as `globalThis` is everywhere the same object.

```js
// module A
globalThis.myVar = 17;

// module B
console.log(globalThis.myVar);
```

You can learn more about `globalThis` here: [MDN:globalThis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis)